# GPU not engaging (improving performance) when using directml-plugin

Tags: gpu, tensorflow2.0, directml

I am trying to train an object detection model on a laptop, which does not have Nvidia GPU, so have to use tensorflow-directml-plugin instead.

I am following the official instructions from MS as found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/directml/gpu-tensorflow-plugin

Here are the TF packages that I have in my venv:
tensorflow-addons               0.21.0
tensorflow-cpu                  2.10.0
tensorflow-datasets             4.9.0
tensorflow-directml-plugin      0.4.0.dev230202
tensorflow-estimator            2.10.0
tensorflow-gpu                  2.10.0
tensorflow-hub                  0.14.0
tensorflow_intel                2.10.0
tensorflow-io                   0.31.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem    0.31.0
tensorflow-metadata             1.13.0
tensorflow-model-optimization   0.7.5
tensorflow-object-detection-api 0.1.1
tensorflow-text                 2.10.0

python = 3.10.2
TF<=2.10.* (should support GPU)

Machine:
CPU = i7-8665U (appears on the list of supported devices)
GPU = Intel UHD Graphics 620 (>500 -> should work fine).
GPU driver v31.0.101.* (the latest)
OS = Win 10 19045.3208 (also meeting requirements here)

print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
confirms that 1 GPU is connected.
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]

However, when I am training a model, I am also not seeing any improvements in computational power. The script runs fine without any errors and confirms that it is attempting to engage GPU, but GPU load is at 6%, which is the same as the level I have when idling.
Any ideas on why it could be the case?

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TOFF.png)